# How to remote debug hazelcast server using eclipse?

Tags: debugging, hazelcast

I have a Hazelcast server running on my local machine. I want to setup remote debugging from my eclipse IDE. When I launch it from Debug configuration, I cant connect.

Thanks
Asgar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following JVM parameters to the Java application that the Hazelcast member is running:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8998,server=y
```

Or if you are using `console.sh` (or `console.bat` if you are running in Windows environment) script, replace the following line:

```
java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -cp ../lib/hazelcast-all-3.9.2.jar com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp
```

with this:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8998,server=y -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -cp ../lib/hazelcast-all-3.9.2.jar com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp
```

Then, you can use Eclipse's "Remote Java Application" configuration in "Run -> Debug Configurations" to configure the remote debugging. Please remind that you need to set the same port as you defined in the JVM parameters (`8998` in the example above). Here is a good tutorial how to do it: https://dzone.com/articles/how-debug-remote-java-applicat

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful. I had to make a small change, instead -XDebug i used -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044

Comment: No problem. If it worked for you, can you please mark this answer as "accepted"? That will help community to see the answer easily.